# Reach to array member using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I trying reach to array member using pointer.
Array's first member adress is 23fe20 ;
When I write '1' the program must show me to 23fe24 (because 23fe20+4*1=23fe24) but not working this way. Program output is : 23fe30.. 
I can use *(pointer+i) for reach to array member but I want reach with adress. How can I do that? Sorry for my english, thanks a lot :'(

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int array[5]={46,85,111,1976,2};
int *pointer,indices;
pointer=array;
int i=0;

printf("Array members : ");
for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    printf("%d ",array[i]);
}
printf("\n\n Array's First member' : %x\n\n",&*pointer);

printf("Which array member do you want to reach? ");
scanf("%d",&indices);


printf("\n Your member adress : %x",pointer+sizeof(int)*indices);

return 0; }
```

Comment: just remove the sizeof(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address you calculate using `sizeof(int)` is already done by the compiler for you. So your calculation make it point to elsewhere (as the same calculation is done twice). You can simply add a integral type to a pointer to get access to an element.

So do:

```
printf("\n Your member adress : %p",(void*) (pointer+indices));
```

You should also use `%p` in the other place where you print address.

Comment: Thank you, what about what means zeros at the beginning of address?

Comment: You mean `pointer + 0` ? That'll give the address of the first element: `&array[0]`.

Comment: I know, I asked when I write a number output is like 00000....023fe24 
I'm asking reason to zeros

Comment: It's just the way address printed by printf in hexa decimal. 023fe24 or 0000023fe24 (in hex) is the same.

Comment: The `(void*)` cast is superfluous.

Comment: @Lundin It is *not* superfluous, but required for `%p` in printf.

Comment: In C, every pointer can get implicitly converted to void* without an explicit cast. Given that the prototype of printf is available (which it must be if you have a somewhat modern compiler with C99), the cast shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @Lundin `void *` to and back conversion applies only for normal assignments (or function arguments), not for variadic function arguments such as printf. So the availability of printf's prototype doesn't change anything. There's no implicit conversion done by printf for pointers. C99 (and C11) has it *The  argument  shall  be  a  pointer  to void.* for format specifier `p`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the behavior you see is that in C, pointers have a type, and addition is defined to add that many *members*, not *bytes*.

Actually, the syntax `array[i]` is the same as `*(array+i)`.

Thus, you either have to remove the multiplication by `sizeof(int)`, or, if you really wanted to explore arithmetic on *adresses*, make `pointer` a `char *` instead, because a character is one byte.

Example:

```
char *cp;
int *ip;
ip = array;
cp = (char *) ip;
printf("%p\n%p\n", ip + 1, cp + 1);
```

would print, assuming `array` is at address 23fe20:

```
23fe24
23fe21
```

(Assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4`)